# Mac OS - specified driver could not be loaded

Tags: drivers, macos, odbc

**Objective**
Goal is to use an odbc connection between bigquery and excel. However, excel can't find the driver per the error image below.

**Steps taken so far**:

1. download odbc driver from [google partner](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers)
2. download [odbc manager](http://www.odbcmanager.net) > open odbc manager > under system dsn > the google bigquery driver is chosen and several key value pairs are filled per this [pg34](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/odbc/SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery-2.4.6.1015.dmg) of this link.

**Error**
First error
[image: First error]

Second error follows first once click "ok"
[image: Second error follows]